# ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method ‘sub’ for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error in the browser when I attempt to view `localhost:3000/galleries`

---

## Routing Error

```
undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass
```

---

My log file tells me

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method ‘sub’ for nil:NilClass)`
  app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  Rendered /Users/mikev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

routes.rb

```
Gallery::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'galleries' => 'galleries#index'  
end
```

controllers/galleries_controller.rb:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
end
```

views/galleries/index.html.erb is empty

Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem usually occurs when the router tries to look up a constant name and fails.

Do you have a helper in app/helpers/galleries_helper.rb? If so, does it define GalleriesHelper?

Comment: I do have a helper in app/helpers/galleries_helper.rb, but it defines `GalleryHelper`  Changed it to `GalleriesHelper` and everything works again!